# Relationship between two conditions on measures

Tags: measure-theory

On page 108 of Mattila's *Geometry of Sets and Measures in Euclidean Spaces*, he defines two conditions on a measure $\mu$ and shows how they are related. I can't for the life of me figure out what he's talking about.

He calls this the "the growth condition", dependent on some positive $c,s$:
$$\begin{equation}
\mu(B(x,r))\leq cr^s \text{ for } x\in\mathbb{R}^n, \text{ } 0<r<\infty. \tag{1}
\end{equation}$$
He calls this the "finiteness of t-energy $I_t(\mu)$":
$$\begin{equation}
I_t(\mu) := \iint|x-y|^{-t} d\mu x d\mu y < \infty. \tag{2}
\end{equation}$$
He then manipulates $(1)$ as follows:
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int|x-y|^{-t} d\mu y &=\int_0^\infty\mu(\{y : |x-y|^{-t} \geq u\})du \\
&= \int_0^\infty\mu(B(x,u^{-1/t}))du \\
&= t \int_0^\infty r^{-t-1}\mu(B(x,r))dr,
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}$$

using change of variables in the last step. This math I'm fine with, but he then claims that "we immediately see" that if $\mu(\mathbb{R}^n)<\infty$ and if for some $s>t$, $\mu(B(x,r))\leq cr^s$, then $I_t(\mu)<\infty$. Can someone justify this claim for me? I see that you can get

$$I_t(\mu)\leq \int t\int_0^\infty cr^{s-t-1} drd\mu x, $$

but I don't see where you can go from there. It seems as if no matter what our exponent is, the integral either will diverge at 0 or as it goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Mattila is discussing positive finite measures here, so the integral over $|x-y|>1$ is automatically finite. Thus you can just integrate over $|x-y| \le 1$,
so in the last integral you consider, it is just the integrability near zero that must be checked.

More formally,
$$\int_0^\infty r^{-t-1}\mu(B(x,r))\,dr \le
\int_0^1 r^{-t-1}cr^s \, dr+ \mu(\mathbb R^n) \cdot\int_1^\infty r^{-t-1}\, dr <\infty \,. $$